# Add Javascript file in Joomla environment

Tags: javascript, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-template

I want to know, how can I upload javascript's files in the Joomla's platform (version 1.5.14)? Because when I try to upload .js files (Site -> Media Manager -> FolderName), Joomla's platform show me next below message:

*"This file type is not supported.".*

Is necesary to install a plugin in the Joomla's platform to upload .js file, or upload in special path in the Joomla's platform?.

**NOTE**: I don't want to include the .js file in the head tag of the html file, because I will include more than 10 .js files, that why, I need to make a references of these javascript files.(I need to upload more than 10 javascript file. (Jquery)).

After that! the references of javascript files doesn't change when I include in my html file to use it (if is possible)?. The way to use is similar than conventional?

I don't want to use javascripts in "*articles*" either "*category*" only in the main page.

Comment: To have the working functionalities of jQuery you must have them attached in head.

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty javascript file in your database (sometimes the template builder has added script or removed this) that you can fill with script, or you can add a js file then still attach in the header to use it.

You have to access outside of your administration access and go directly to the files in your template folder for the template you are using. There are workarounds to do some of this from yoursite.com/administrator but you are limited to the template you are using and the functions they offer.